# Error "IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 3, Size: 3" while running hive code

Tags: hadoop, hive

I run the code below everyday and it succeed every time. But when I run it today, there comes an error IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 3, Size: 3. When I deleted the clause "`where member_srl is not null`", it succeed. So I don't know what is wrong with my code. And why it can not run today. Thanks.

```
select   member_srl, dt, sessionid  , (max(reg_time)-min(reg_time)) as duration, count(reg_time) as click_cnt 
      from
       (
         select cast(member_srl as bigint) as member_srl, reg_date as dt, sessionid, cast(SUBSTRING(reg_time,1,2)*3600+SUBSTRING(reg_time,3,2)*60+SUBSTRING(reg_time,5,2) as bigint) as reg_time
         from default.daily_session 
         where member_srl<>'' and dt = '20161009'
        union all
        select cast(member_srl as bigint) as member_srl, reg_date as dt, sessionid, cast(SUBSTRING(reg_time,1,2)*3600+SUBSTRING(reg_time,3,2)*60+SUBSTRING(reg_time,5,2) as bigint) as reg_time
         from default.daily_session_mobile  
         where member_srl<>'' and dt = '20161009'
        union all 
        select cast(member_srl as bigint) as member_srl, reg_date as dt, sessionid, cast(SUBSTRING(reg_time,1,2)*3600+SUBSTRING(reg_time,3,2)*60+SUBSTRING(reg_time,5,2) as bigint) as reg_time
         from default.daily_session_ios  
         where member_srl<>'' and dt = '20161009'
       ) base  where member_srl is not null 
       group by member_srl, dt, sessionid
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11603), and have been solved in version 1.3.0.

If you are using old version like me, then `set hive.optimize.ppd=false;` to solve your problem.(deprecated)

My version is Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.6.0

I set hive.optimize.ppd to false, and found that filter on partitioned field do not work,and all those partitions in partitioned table will be read by mapper.

Finally.

I changed my query, use one more subquery solved the problem.